# Why the find function is not working in comparing two data properties in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

When the value of `Id` of `stateGDP` and the `rank` of `statesJson` are equal to each other, then they should be shown as output. But there is some error which I am not getting.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
    statesJson:{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{ "rank":"1", "NAME_1": "Andaman and Nicobar"},
             { "rank":"2", "NAME_1": "Rajasthan"},
             { "rank":"3", "NAME_1": "Orissa"}]
    },
    
    stateGDP:[{ "Id":"1", "NAME_1": "Andaman and Nicobar","2000":"48"},
             { "Id":"2", "NAME_1": "Rajasthan","2000":"87"},
             { "Id":"3", "NAME_1": "Orissa","2000":"25"}]
    }
  },
   computed:{ 
    check(){
      let x = this.statesJson.features.map(feature =>{ return feature.rank})
      let stateData = this.stateGDP.find(state => state.Id === x)
      return x
    }
  }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="state in check">
       {{state}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because map returns an array. To fix your code all you have to do is to check if `x` contains your id.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      statesJson: {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
          { "rank":"1", "NAME_1": "Andaman and Nicobar"},
          { "rank":"2", "NAME_1": "Rajasthan"},
          { "rank":"3", "NAME_1": "Orissa"},
        ]
      },
    
      stateGDP: [
        { "Id":"1", "NAME_1": "Andaman and Nicobar","2000":"48"},
        { "Id":"2", "NAME_1": "Rajasthan","2000":"87"},
        { "Id":"3", "NAME_1": "Orissa","2000":"25"},
      ],   
    }
  },
  computed:{ 
    check(){
      let state = this.statesJson.features.map(feature => {
        return this.stateGDP.find(state => state.Id === feature.rank);
      });
      
      return state;
    }
  },
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <strong>Total object</strong><hr/>
  <div v-for="state in check">
    {{ state }}
  </div>
  
  <br/>
  
  <strong>Seperate variables</strong><hr/>
  <div v-for="state in check">
    Id = {{ state["Id"] }}<br/>
    Name_1 = {{ state["NAME_1"] }}<br/>
    2000 = {{ state["2000"] }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually you haven't got what I want. I want that as v-for iterates the value of Ids should be shown in the output but the condition is Id should be equal to statesJson rank.

Comment: @LakshayKhandelwal I'm not sure what you mean, can you maybe add the desired output to your question?

Comment: I have updated the code and I just only want that as `v-for` iterates if the Id is equaled to rank in that iteration then that element of stateGDP should be assigned in the stateData variable. For example, in the first iteration the rank would be 1 and if it is equal to Id (which should be 1) then stateData should get this `{ "Id":"1", "NAME_1": "Andaman and Nicobar","2000":"48"}`.

Comment: You mean something like this? For every iteration it gets the rank. Then returns the stateGDP that has the same Id.

Comment: can you do me one more favor, please?